# Memory used by one object and its dependencies

Tags: c#, memory-management

In C# is it possible to know how many bytes are being allocated by one object and its dependencies? I know I can use dotMemory to do that, but is there a way from the GC or something to get that from C#?

For instance if I have this:

```
var x = new Tuple<int,int>[3] { Tuple.Create(0,0), Tuple.Create(0,0), Tuple.Create(0,0) };
```

I am looking for a function like: `x.GetTotalMemorySize()` that returns `76 = 16 + 3 * (4 + (8 + 8)))`

ie:

`16` is the number of bytes used in array overhead

`3` is the number of elements in the array

`4` is the bytes used by the Tuple pointers

`8 + 8` is the bytes used by the ints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a free [dotMemory Unit](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/unit/) framework to measure a memory from code

```
    var x = new Tuple<int,int>[3] { Tuple.Create(0,0), Tuple.Create(0,0), Tuple.Create(0,0) };
    dotMemory.Check(memory =>
    {
      var objectSet = memory.GetObjects(where => where.Type.Is<Tuple<int, int>[]>())
                            .GetExclusivelyRetainedObjects();

      Console.WriteLine(objectSet);
    });
    GC.KeepAlive(x);
```

**Output:** ObjectsCount: 4; SizeInBytes: 128

**UPDATED:** Of course I should selected array type "Tuple< int, int>[]" instead of "Tuple< int, int>". Updated the code and the output

Answer (score 1):

If you have a sterile environment, you can use [`GC.GetTotalMemory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.gettotalmemory(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
void Main()
{
    GC.Collect(2);
    var before = GC.GetTotalMemory(false);
    Console.WriteLine($"Before: {before}");
    var x = new Tuple<int,int>[3] { Tuple.Create(0,0), 
                                    Tuple.Create(0,0), 
                                    Tuple.Create(0,0) };

    var after = GC.GetTotalMemory(false);
    Console.WriteLine($"After: {after}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Diff was: {after - before}");
}
```

Comment: Sure, that helps, but it's not quite the same, and you have to reproduce the whole structure you want to measure so it's quite painful. Plus the optimizer might optimize the allocations away if you're not careful...

Comment: @d--b I'm not quite sure what "not quite the same* means. Yes, you have to reproduce the whole structure, but that's what you asked for. Doing this at runtime is nearly impossible to get accurate, as you have a bunch of dependencies affecting the GC. I would stick to using a profiler for that.

Comment: It's not quite the same because according to the C# documentation: `GC.GetTotalMemory is the best available approximation of the number of bytes currently allocated in managed memory`

Comment: @d--b It's the best you can get via code. If you really want to look debugger, you can use `WinDBG` to explore the runtime.